# Where is the Boundedness Assumption Used?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> A set of real numbers is said to be a $G_\delta$ set provided it is the intersection of a countable collection of open sets. Show that for any bounded set $E$, there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ for which $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(G)=m^*(E)$.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{A} := \{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k \mid \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k \text{ covers } E \}$, and define $G = \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A$. Since $E \subseteq A$ for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, we have that $E \subseteq G$, which in turn implies $m^*(E) \le m^*(G)$. Now let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists a cover $\{I_{k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k) \le m^*(E) + \varepsilon$. Notice that $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k \in \mathcal{A}$, so that $G \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$, and therefore $m^*(G) \le m^*(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k) \le m^*(E) + \varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, we arrive at $m^*(G) \le m^*(E)$, and therefore $m^*(G) = m^*(E)$.

First of all, does this seem right? Secondly, where is the boundedness assumption of $E$ used? I know that boundedness implies that the measure is finite, but I can't determine where, if at all, this is used.

Comment: If $E$ were unbounded, it would be trivial:  $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ is a $G_\delta$ set (being the one-fold intersection of itself...?  there has to be a better way of saying that) and both have infinite (pre)measure.

Comment: $m^*$ is the outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$? Also, why is $\mathcal{A}$ countable?

Comment: @Xander Henderson: $E$ could be unbounded and have finite outer measure. But making $E$ bounded is a simple way of guaranteeing that its outer measure is finite.

Comment: @mechanodroid hmm...I am not sure at the moment...And yes: $m^*$ is indeed the outer measure.

Comment: @mechanodroid I don't think my proof relies on whether $\mathcal{A}$ is countable or not.

Comment: Oi... I'm an idiot.  I read $E$ was open.  Ignore me.  I'd delete the original comment, but it would probably make the rest of this thread look strange.

Comment: Yes it does. A $G_{\delta}$ set is a countable intersection of open sets. Hmm...Perhaps I can use boundedness of $E$ and take the closure of $E$. This will give a compact set for which every open cover has a finite subcover. Not sure if that is helpful...

Comment: Your proof does rely on the countability of $\mathcal{A}$, assuming you intend for $G = \bigcap_{A\in \mathcal{A}} A$ to be your $G_{\delta}$ set. But $\mathcal{A}$ is certainly uncountable, unless you add more restrictions.

Comment: @user193319 but then how do you know that $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set? It is supposed to be a countable intersection of open sets. I tried to circumvent this issue in my answer below, using essentially the same construction.

Comment: If $m^*(E)<\infty$ the proof applies verbatim whether $E$ is bounded or not. If $m^*(E)=\infty$ we can  let  $G=\mathbb R.$ So it's true for all $E.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something similar to your construction:

Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the definition of outer measure, there exists a cover $(I^{(n)}_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda(I^{(n)}_k)  \leq m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}$. Now set $G = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k$. G is a countable intersection of open sets so it is a $G_\delta$ set. Also we have $E \subseteq G$. By monotonicity of outer measure we have $m^*(E) \leq m^*(G)$. Also, by subadditivity of outer measure we have:
$$m^*(G) \leq m^*\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I^{(n)}_k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda(I^{(n)}_k) \leq m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}m^*(E)$$

Thus, $m^*(E) = m^*(G)$.

Comment: Just clarification for my own sake: in the next to last line, are you using the fact that $G = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k$ for every $n$ to conclude $m^*(G) \le m^*(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k) \le m^*(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I^{(n)}_k) \le ...$?

Comment: @user193319 Yes, along with monotonicity of $m^*$.